# How to have one covariant parameter in a class as well as a function to transform it?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have a very simple class:

```
case class Foo[+T](t: T)
```

Now I want to add a argument to transform T to Int. For specific reasons, I do not want to use a typeclass, an implicit or any inheritance based solution because this is really what I am modeling: a class containing some data and the function to transform it.

So I write

```
case class Foo[+T](t: T, f: T => Int)
```

or

```
case class Foo[+T](t: T, f: Function1[T, Int])
```

Of course, it doesn't work because f is contravariant on T.
Any solution?

Comment: If the function needs to transform the data item that actually sits in the object, then it should not accept any parameters. Otherwise, your question boils down to "how do I make the function parameter covariant?" You could just as well ask "how do I make 3 even?"

Answer (score 2):

You could try existential type

```
case class Foo[+T](t: T, f: (_ <: T) => Int)
```

but actually `(_ <: T) => Int` is just `Nothing => Int`.

(In Dotty it's also possible to have `case class Foo[+T](t: T, f: [U <: T] => U => Int)`.)

Consider adding one more type parameter

```
case class Foo[+T, U <: T](t: T, f: U => Int)
```

Then you can use "partially applied" pattern when you want `U` to be inferred

```
def mkFoo[T] = new PartiallyApplied[T]
class PartiallyApplied[T] {
  def apply[U <: T](t: T, f: U => Int) = Foo(t, f)
}

trait Parent
case class Child(i: Int) extends Parent

mkFoo[Parent](new Parent {}, (c: Child) => c.i)
```

One more option is to make `U` a type member

```
trait Foo[+T] {
  type U <: T
  val t: T
  val f: U => Int
}

object Foo {
  def apply[T, _U <: T](_t: T, _f: _U => Int): Foo[T] { type U = _U } = new Foo[T] {
    override type U = _U
    override val t: T = _t
    override val f: U => Int = _f
  }

  def unapply[T](foo: Foo[T]): Option[(T, foo.U => Int)] = Some((foo.t, foo.f))
}
```

---

Maybe your class can be

```
case class Foo[+T](t: T) { 
  def f[U >: T](t1: U): Int = ??? 
}
```

Otherwise it's just invariant `case class Foo[T](t: T, f: T => Int)`.

Comment: How would you call Foo.f?

Comment: In your example, U <: T. But I would need U >: T because the function is contravariant. For instance, if T = Int, I want to be able to pass (x: Int) => x *2 or (x: Any) => 42. And another thing: I would really need Foo to be a case class as I depend on this for others things such as automatic persistence.

Comment: @pm42 If `U >: T` then `Foo` is just not covariant with respect to `T` (if there were no `t` you could make `Foo` contravariant `Foo[-T]` but now with `t` and `f` it's just invariant). You can't change variance on your discretion. You can make `Foo` covariant (`Foo[+T]`) if `Foo[Int]` is a `Foo[Any]` but your `Foo[Int]` is not a `Foo[Any]` because `(x: Int) => x *2` is not a function `Any => Int`.

Comment: @pm42 Actually this starts to sound like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you solving with trying to make `Foo` covariant (while it's not)?

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin: I'm trying to modelize a couple data source/data transformation. So I want to store in one case class both a source of data, i.e. covariant like any collection/stream. In the same class, I want to store a function transforming this data source into another type.

Comment: @pm42 Let's consider `List`. It's covariant because it doesn't contain `A => ...` Notice that [prepending an element](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L97) has signature `def :: [B >: A](elem: B): List[B]`. With signature `def :: (elem: A): List[A]` list wouldn't be covariant. `Map[K, V]` is covariant with respect to `V` but not with respect to `K` (because maps are like `K => V`). `Set` is invariant. All mutable collections are invariant. So not all collections are covariant. Sounds like your collection is not either.

Comment: @pm42 You said it should be a case class because you use automatic persistence. Are you sure you need to persist function? How is the function stored? I suspect like a hash `App$$$Lambda$1/189568618@21a06946`. Does it make much sense to persist a function?

Comment: @pm42 Maybe your class can be `case class Foo[+T](t: T) {
    def f[U >: T](t1: U): Int = ???
  }`. Otherwise it's just invariant `case class Foo[T](t: T, f: T => Int)`.

Comment: In the real case, I will not pass the function as a lambda but as an implementation of the Function1 scala trait. It will be a case class containing for instance a string to be interpreted. This "function" is just an argument like any other

Comment: @pm42 Why not to make `Foo` invariant (since it **is** invariant)?

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin: yes, this is the solution. Talking to you helped me understand something I did not get before. Thanks.